# Delete elements from a simple linked list starting at given position

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have implemented this function in this way:

```
typedef node* List;
void DeleteFromPos(List &l, unsigned int p) {
    List lAux = l;
    unsigned int count = 1;

    while (lAux) {      
        if (p == 1) {
            while (l) {
                List del = lAux;
                lAux = lAux->next;
                delete del;
                del = NULL;
            }
            lAux = NULL;
        } else if (count < p-1) {
                lAux = lAux->next;
                count++;
        } else {
            List del = lAux->next;
            if (del) {
                lAux->next = del->next;
                delete del;
                del = NULL;
            } else
                lAux = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when p==1, in this especial case all the elements are deleted but it looks like the l pointer still exist at the end. 
I need some advice about this.

EDIT: with some sugerence, the p ==1 case have his own loop, its ugly but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your task by modularising. First have a function that deletes all elements in a list.

```
deleteList(List *&head) {
   while (head) {
      List *l = head->next;
      delete head;
      head = l;
   }
}
```

Note *& - reference to a pointer. Thus the function modifies head parameter.

Then have a function that locates n-th element. When you have n-th node call the above function.

If you really need to do the job in a single function then do something like:

```
deleteFromPosition(List *&head, unsigned int pos) {
  loop one: iterate through the list until n-th node is reached;
  loop two: iterate through the list tail deleting nodes as in the function above;
}
```

I am leaving details out for your exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is homework and im not allowed to do that.

Comment: Not allowed to do what? Write a correct code that is easy to write, read and understand?

Comment: The idea is to write that function without auxiliar methods, traversing the list only once.

Comment: In your deleteFromPosition function traverse the list until you've found n-th element. Then use the body of the function I show in the answer. You'll traverse the list once but in two separate distinct steps which do their own work.

Comment: See mi edit, if that is what you mean. It doesnt look very clean code but it work at least

Comment: Your code can be improved. Remove outer loop. `function(){ loop_to_find_n-th-node; loop-to-delete-the-tail;}` Also no need for `del = NULL;` and `lAux = NULL;` The later is achieved with `l=l->next;` Next will be NULL eventually.

Comment: Also you may need to modify the head of a list passed to `deleteFromPosition()` function. Pass reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void DeleteFromPos(List &l, unsigned int p)
```

I believe you pass a pointer to `node` by reference so that if the head of your list is to be deleted, you can update the pointer itself so that this change is visible to the caller. Yet you do:

```
List lAux = l;
```

which throws this potential away. In case `p` equals `1`, you should do:

```
if (p == 1) {
    List del = l;
    l = l->next;   // <-- updates pointer that was passed by reference
    delete del;
}
```

Comment: im getting an exception in "l = l->next;", There is not a while(l) to stop at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer l is not changed in your function. You change pointer lAux but l keeps its original value.